# Is replacing an assignment with an Expression possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

I have a method of a Web API controller which queries the DB and returns data:

```
public IQueryable<DeviceInformation> GetAllRegisteredDevices()
{
    var result = this.db.CustomDeviceInstallations.Select(install => new DeviceInformation
    {
        Platform =
            install.Platform == NotificationPlatform.Apns ? PLATFORM.iOS :
            install.Platform == NotificationPlatform.Gcm ? PLATFORM.Android :
            PLATFORM.Unknown
    });

    return result;
}
```

What bugs me in this method is the decision about the platform being assigned. I will need the same decision in other contexts and therefore would like to extract it, so I ended up with:

```
public Expression<Func<NotificationPlatform, PLATFORM>> ToDeviceInfoPlatformExpression()
{
    return p =>
        p == NotificationPlatform.Apns ? PLATFORM.iOS :
        p == NotificationPlatform.Gcm ? PLATFORM.Android :
        PLATFORM.Unknown;
}
```

The question is now: how can I use my expression? `Platform = ????` Is it possible at all?

**Note:** I know I could instead use an extension method and also use a switch-case for readability. However, the code above is used in context of Entity Framework and must be an expression. This also rules out the use of `Expression.Compile()`.

Comment: It's unclear why you're using an expression tree at all. What's wrong with your original code?

Comment: Mainly curiosity. Secondary: having the same assignment multiple times without copying the code.

Comment: Wow, frankly, I'm surprised by the "close" votes and the down voting. I thought this would be an interesting question. But it seems I was completely wrong.

Comment: I think you should edit the question to show more context. Presumably this assignment is *actually* within an object initializer, as part of the query - but you never say as much. You say it's "in context of Entity Framework" but being more specific would be useful.

Comment: What are you asking is not possible out of the box. You'll need some 3rd party library like LinqKit.

Comment: @Krumelur - The close votes are because folks don't understand your question. You might want to show more context - how the code would be used, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not possible without some expression helper library.

Here is how you can do that with [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) using `AsExpandable` and `Invoke` extension methods:

```
// First you need to put the expression into a variable
// Without that you'll get the famous EF method not supported exception
var deviceInfoPlatform = ToDeviceInfoPlatformExpression();
// Then you can use it inside the query
var result = this.db.CustomDeviceInstallations
    .AsExpandable()
    .Select(install => new DeviceInformation
    {
        Platform = deviceInfoPlatform.Invoke(install.Platform)
    });
```